# Makefile for data sicience workflow

Tags: csv, makefile

I'm writing a makefile to automate so of the tasks that I need to do for a project.

One of the tasks is to extract csv files from gz archives.
I do not know the names of gz archives nor csv files beforehand.

I wrote following rule(with real tabs) to do the task.

```
data/%.gz: data/%.csv
    echo "extract" $@ "from" $<
    gzip -d -k ./data/$*
```

Problem is it does not execute when I try to execute:

```
process_new_data: data/%.gz
   some_script.sh
```

What did I do wrong? 
As I understood my file extraction rule should be executed once for each gz archive found in data folder.

Comment: What exactly should `process_new_data` do with what files (.csv or .gz)?

Comment: it is just one script reads the data and processes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule for extracting CSV files should be "reversed":

```
data/%.csv: data/%.gz
    echo "extract" $@ "from" $<
    gzip -d -k ./data/$*
```

The syntax os:

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipe
```

The complete `Makefile` would use `wildcard` and `patsubst` functions:

```
GZ_FILES = $(wildcard data/*.gz)
CSV_FILES = $(patsubst data/%.gz, data/%.csv, $(GZ_FILES))

process_new_data: $(CSV_FILES)
    ./some_script.sh

data/%.csv: data/%.gz
    echo "extract" $@ "from" $<
    gzip -d -k ./data/$*
```